# What is a "could not find type System.Collections.Generic.List" in the .NET Designer?

Tags: c#

I've got a WinForms project that I've had for quite some time, and now suddenly, I can't open the designer anymore and when I try to open the designer I get an error that says

could not find type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

All of the code builds just fine, but I can't use the designer anymore, and I don't know what happened, nor do I have any idea where to look to solve the problem. Has anyone ever run into this or have any insight?

Comment: Has the designer file been hand edited? Sound like you are missing a Using Statement somewhere.

Comment: This is old school 2.0 .NET, so the designer file and the code file are one in the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just in case anyone is curious, here's what happened.

Somehow, via accident a line of code got added into the Forms InitializeComponent Method that was basically just constructing a generic list. Simple code, no big deal, and it compiled just fine.

Well it seems that you can't put anything with Generics in the InitializeComponent method. I'm not sure why you'd ever need to do it, but if you're seeing this error, make sure you don't have any generic code in InitializeComponent.

Comment: Had the same problem so I did this, but then also had to delete the <value> block for the <data> of this item in the .resx to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Unload and re-load you project. Rebuild and open your form in Designer view. If your code is compilable, this should do the trick.

Comment: Then please try restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you just making stuff up? Because I feel like I'm on the phone with Microsoft support circa 1995.

Comment: I'm sorry it sounds like that (as a joke, you know Microsoft recommends restarting everything that stops working). However, I usually get rid of similar issues this way.

Comment: Old thread - but Google hit it. Had this problem with embedded user controls all of a sudden. The above worked for me. Note that I could compile clean (clean solution made no difference) and open each of the supposedly missing types directly, but designer failed on just about ever sub-control. Unload/reload/rebuild worked with no other change needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you maybe changed the .NET version of the project?

Also, try removing and regenerating the designer file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your solution and build again. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

All prior answers did not work for me.
Here is how I fixed the issue:

1) Remove all custom code from the .designer.cs file.

2) Make sure a default constructor is implemented - adding arguments to the constructor breaks the designer view since for that one the default constructor is attempted to be called.

So with the System.Collections.Generic reference in the form.cs file and not the form.designer.cs file and with default constructors present it started to work fine - no solution reload needed.